How do I use twist mux cmd vel out for the robot motion
Twist_mux not working
I am using twist mux to switch between two cmd_vel, one is from a node that publishes twist x 0 whenever a blue box is detected through camera called /cmd_vel_tracker and another is /cmd_vel which is published from nav2 navigation, I have given higher priority to /cmd_vel_tracker and even checked if the node is publishing by doing topic echo, but for some reason twist_mux isnt prioritising this and still navigating to the pose. What could be the reason the twist mux isn't working as needed, I'm pretty sure I'm using unstamped twist so there should'nt have been any problem. Please help. Here is my rqt graph. What can I do to make the twist mux work.
